# Why does this happens to my tkinter code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

So I made a image viewer another day and basically what it does is to skip into next image and get back to the first one when our set of pictures are over.
I made a button called <kbd>Start</kbd>which basically starts the whole picture viewer and displays picture number 1,
and I also made a <kbd>Close</kbd> button which reverses the whole thing to the starting point (you will see the start button again).

...But a very weird thing happens.
when I press my buttons is this order : `Start`, `Next`, Close`,` Start`,` Next` — the whole thing goes crazy and my buttons fade away!

Sorry if I wrote the code in a very inefficient way and that's because I started learning python 2 days ago!
I also made this print at the end of each `if`/`elif` to make it easier for debug but it didn't help.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from tkinter.font import *
root = Tk()
img = None
label1 = None
root.geometry('1920x1080')
cimage = "flower1.jpg"
# Functions
def rightpic() :
    global cimage
    if cimage == "flower1.jpg" :
        label1.grid_forget()
        label2.grid()
        cimage = "flower2.jpg"
        print("flower1skip")
    elif cimage == "flower2.jpg" :
        label2.grid_forget()
        label3.grid()
        cimage = "flower3.jpg"
        print("flower2skip")
    elif cimage == "flower3.jpg" :
        label3.grid_forget()
        label4.grid()
        cimage = "flower4.jpg"
        print("flower3skip")
    elif cimage == "flower4.jpg" :
        label4.grid_forget()
        label1.grid()
        cimage = "flower1.jpg"
        print("flower4skip")
def start() :
    global cimage
    label1.grid(row=0)
    buttonright.place(x=900, y=950)
    buttonclose.place(x=700, y=950)
def close() :
    global cimage
    if cimage == "flower1.jpg" :
        label1.grid_forget()
        buttonclose.place_forget()
        buttonright.place_forget()
        print("closed1")
    elif cimage == "flower2.jpg" :
        label2.grid_forget()
        buttonclose.place_forget()
        buttonright.place_forget()
        print("closed2")
    elif cimage == "flower3.jpg" :
        label3.grid_forget()
        buttonclose.place_forget()
        buttonright.place_forget()
        print("closed3")
    elif cimage == "flower4.jpg" :
        label4.grid_forget()
        buttonclose.place_forget()
        buttonright.place_forget()
        print("closed4")

buttons = Button(root,text = "Start!",command=start , bg = "#29a8ab",fg="#cccccc" , padx = 50 ,font=('Helvetica 19 bold'))
buttons.place(x=960,y=540)

buttonright= Button(root,text = "Next!",command=rightpic , bg = "#0e9aa7",fg="#f6cd61" , padx = 50 ,font=('Helvetica 19 bold'))
# buttonright.place(x=900, y=950)
buttonclose= Button(root,text = "Close!",command=close , bg = "#0e9aa7",fg="#f6cd61" , padx = 50 ,font=('Helvetica 19 bold'))





image1 = Image.open("flower1.jpg")
image1 = image1.resize((1920,950) , Image.ANTIALIAS)
image12 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
label1 = Label(root,image=image12)

image2 = Image.open("flower2.jpg")
image2 = image2.resize((1920,950) , Image.ANTIALIAS)
image13 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
label2 = Label(root,image=image13)

image3 = Image.open("flower3.jpg")
image3 = image3.resize((1920,950) , Image.ANTIALIAS)
image14 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image3)
label3 = Label(root,image=image14)

image4 = Image.open("flower4.jpg")
image4 = image4.resize((1920,950) , Image.ANTIALIAS)
image15 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image4)
label4 = Label(root,image=image15)

# label1.grid(row = 0)

mainloop()
```

Comment: The issue is quite funny and it is that the second (and other) time you call `next()` the `cimage` is still set to the second image so it acts as if it had to grid the third one, that probably pushes out everything out of the window, the easiest is to probably add `cimage = 'flower1.jpg'` at the beginning of `start()` function def, I will probably write a proper answer (in a few hours) and will also try to show how to improve your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I will answer the question: why do buttons disappear when they are clicked in that sequence?
This is because when `start()` is called it grids the first image, then when `rightpic()` gets called, it checks what is the value of `cimage` and acts accordingly, since when you first start the program the value is set to `"flower1.jpg"` it evals the first if statement and forgets the first image gridded and grids the second image, then you call `close()`, again it checks the image and removes everything, however, `cimage` is now `"flower2.jpg"` and when you call `start()` again it grids the first image, but when calling `rightpic()` it goes to the `elif cimage == "fower2.jpg"` but since the second image is not gridded yet, there is nothing to forget, so it simply grids the third image below the first one and since the other buttons are `place()`d then this grid method as it was called after `place()` now puts the third image over those buttons.
The solution is to simply do this:

```py
def start() :
    global cimage
    cimage = "flower1.jpg"
    label1.grid(row=0)
    buttonright.place(x=900, y=950)
    buttonclose.place(x=700, y=950)
```

This will reset the variable to the first image every time `start()` is called.

With this out of the way I will now show you how you can improve your code (because answer has to contain an actual answer to the question not just suggestions), the main issue being creating unnecessary labels and vast amounts of repetition.

**Important**
I would like to mention this before other stuff: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.
Also I would like to strongly suggest that you follow [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), for example have two lines between function definitions, have a space after comma (`,`) but not before, don't put unnecessary spaces such as `def func() :` when it should be `def func():`, in general have consistent formatting, for function and variable names use `snake_case`, for class names use `CapitalCase`. You can simply take a look at the code I will write here to better understand what I mean.

---

The first improvement (that also can be improved but about that later) is to have only one label that simply gets configured (read comments in code):

```py
# import only what you need to keep the namespace clean
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


# my preference is to define everything that doesn't have to be defined
# after instantiating `Tk` before `Tk` such as these variables and functions
# as they will be called after `Tk` anyways so doesn't really matter but at least helps keep
# the parts that are strictly `tkinter` more together
cimage = "flower1.jpg"


# Functions (changed to `snake_case`)
def right_pic():
    # here come some major changes to reduce the code
    # what is commented out can be deleted and is how
    # it were previously
    global cimage
    if cimage == "flower1.jpg":
        # label1.grid_forget()
        # label2.grid()
        image_label.config(image=image13)
        cimage = "flower2.jpg"
        # print("flower1skip")
    elif cimage == "flower2.jpg":
        # label2.grid_forget()
        # label3.grid()
        image_label.config(image=image14)
        cimage = "flower3.jpg"
        # print("flower2skip")
    elif cimage == "flower3.jpg":
        # label3.grid_forget()
        # label4.grid()
        image_label.config(image=image15)
        cimage = "flower4.jpg"
        # print("flower3skip")
    elif cimage == "flower4.jpg":
        # label4.grid_forget()
        # label1.grid()
        image_label.config(image=image12)
        cimage = "flower1.jpg"
        # print("flower4skip")


# put two spaces between funcs (if you have a comment like this that corresponds
# to the function then it also has have two spaces between other functions)
def start():
    global cimage
    cimage = "flower1.jpg"
    image_label.grid(row=0)
    button_right.place(x=900, y=950)
    button_close.place(x=700, y=950)


def close():
    # here comes the first redundant code (if you read line by line)
    # if you notice then every if/elif clause you always call
    # button_right.place_forget() and button_close.place_forget()
    # since they get always called might as well simply put them only at the end
    # (commented out what can be deleted) (what has double ## was even more before)
    # global cimage
    # if cimage == "flower1.jpg":
    #     label1.grid_forget()
    #     # button_close.place_forget()
    #     # button_right.place_forget()
    #     print("closed1")
    # elif cimage == "flower2.jpg":
    #     label2.grid_forget()
    #     # button_close.place_forget()
    #     # button_right.place_forget()
    #     print("closed2")
    # elif cimage == "flower3.jpg":
    #     label3.grid_forget()
    #     # button_close.place_forget()
    #     # button_right.place_forget()
    #     print("closed3")
    # elif cimage == "flower4.jpg":
    #     label4.grid_forget()
    #     # button_close.place_forget()
    #     # button_right.place_forget()
    #     print("closed4")
    # 
    # # simply have these here at the end, no need to repeat them in each clause
    # button_close.place_forget()
    # button_right.place_forget()
    
    # the latest version using only one label is as simple as
    image_label.grid_forget()
    button_close.place_forget()
    button_close.place_forget()


root = Tk()
root.geometry('1920x1080')

buttons = Button(root, text="Start!", command=start, bg="#29a8ab", fg="#cccccc", padx=50, font='Helvetica 19 bold')
buttons.place(x=960, y=540)

# changed names to match `snake_case`, the main changes are minor
# things such as removing spaces or adding those where needed (take a close look
# this is how it should be to be PEP 8 compliant (not necessary to follow but
# it is how python code was intended to be formatted))
button_right = Button(root, text="Next!", command=right_pic, bg="#0e9aa7", fg="#f6cd61", padx=50, font='Helvetica 19 bold')
button_close = Button(root, text="Close!", command=close, bg="#0e9aa7", fg="#f6cd61", padx=50, font='Helvetica 19 bold')

# here comes the second repetition (commented out can be deleted)
# if you wanted to make it even more compact you could have done
# sth like this:
# image1 = Image.open("flower1.jpg").resize((1920, 950), Image.ANTIALIAS)
# image12 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)

image1 = Image.open("flower1.jpg")
image1 = image1.resize((1920, 950), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image12 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
# label1 = Label(root, image=image12)

image2 = Image.open("flower2.jpg")
image2 = image2.resize((1920, 950), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image13 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
# label2 = Label(root, image=image13)

image3 = Image.open("flower3.jpg")
image3 = image3.resize((1920, 950), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image14 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image3)
# label3 = Label(root, image=image14)

image4 = Image.open("flower4.jpg")
image4 = image4.resize((1920, 950), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image15 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image4)
# label4 = Label(root, image=image15)

image_label = Label(root, image=image12)

# best practice is to use `<Tk>.mainloop()` instead of plain `mainloop()`
# so in this case `Tk` is assigned to `root` so this:
root.mainloop()
```

And the same code just deleted comments:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


cimage = "flower1.jpg"


def right_pic():
    global cimage
    if cimage == "flower1.jpg":
        image_label.config(image=image13)
        cimage = "flower2.jpg"
    elif cimage == "flower2.jpg":
        image_label.config(image=image14)
        cimage = "flower3.jpg"
    elif cimage == "flower3.jpg":
        image_label.config(image=image15)
        cimage = "flower4.jpg"
    elif cimage == "flower4.jpg":
        image_label.config(image=image12)
        cimage = "flower1.jpg"


def start():
    global cimage
    cimage = "flower1.jpg"
    image_label.grid(row=0)
    button_right.place(x=900, y=950)
    button_close.place(x=700, y=950)


def close():
    image_label.grid_forget()
    button_close.place_forget()
    button_close.place_forget()


root = Tk()
root.geometry('1920x1080')

buttons = Button(root, text="Start!", command=start, bg="#29a8ab", fg="#cccccc", padx=50, font='Helvetica 19 bold')
buttons.place(x=960, y=540)

button_right = Button(root, text="Next!", command=right_pic, bg="#0e9aa7", fg="#f6cd61", padx=50, font='Helvetica 19 bold')
button_close = Button(root, text="Close!", command=close, bg="#0e9aa7", fg="#f6cd61", padx=50, font='Helvetica 19 bold')


image1 = Image.open("flower1.jpg")
image1 = image1.resize((1920, 950), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image12 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)

image2 = Image.open("flower2.jpg")
image2 = image2.resize((1920, 950), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image13 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)

image3 = Image.open("flower3.jpg")
image3 = image3.resize((1920, 950), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image14 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image3)

image4 = Image.open("flower4.jpg")
image4 = image4.resize((1920, 950), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image15 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image4)

image_label = Label(root, image=image12)

root.mainloop()
```

(as you can see the code is way shorter already)

Now for quite an advanced method that doesn't use `if/elif` the way you used it, basically very expandable:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


# define some lists here (since no direct relation to `tkinter`)
# the main loop is after `Tk`

# note that these are basically relative paths to images (also note that now
# to add new image you really only need to add it to this list)
img_names = ['flower1.jpg', 'flower2.jpg', 'flower3.jpg', 'flower4.jpg']
# another fancier option would be to use sth like this:
# import os
# img_names = [f'images/{name}' for name in os.listdir('images')]
# now this would create a list of relative paths to all files listed in
# directory named `"images"` that is relative to this script (obs
# you can change the dir name and stuff, this is just an example)
# so now if you only had images in that dir, you could simply only
# add images to that directory and they will be added to this list every time you
# run this code which is great

# this is to keep track of the current index, that allows for easier looping
# note tho that there are many options of how to loop over
# those images, this should be the most understandable tho
index = 0


def right_pic():
    # now that there is an image list you can simply iterate over that
    # keeping track of the index
    global index
    index += 1
    # add this if statement to not cause errors
    # and to allow for looping over
    if index == len(img_lst):  # use length because the last index is the length - 1
        index = 0
    image_label.config(image=img_lst[index])


def start():
    # define index as global so that it can be changed
    global index
    # reset it to 0 every time you call `start()`
    index = 0
    # config the label to now contain the first image
    image_label.config(image=img_lst[index])
    image_label.grid(row=0)
    button_right.place(x=900, y=950)
    button_close.place(x=700, y=950)


def close():
    image_label.grid_forget()
    button_close.place_forget()
    button_close.place_forget()


root = Tk()
root.geometry('1920x1080')

# create images and append to the above defined list
img_lst = []
for img in img_names:
    image = Image.open(img).resize((1920, 950), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    img_lst.append(photo)
# a short list comprehension to do this exact same thing but in one line:
# img_lst = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(img_name).resize((1920, 950), Image.ANTIALIAS)) for img_name in img_names]

buttons = Button(root, text="Start!", command=start, bg="#29a8ab", fg="#cccccc", padx=50, font='Helvetica 19 bold')
buttons.place(x=960, y=540)

button_right = Button(root, text="Next!", command=right_pic, bg="#0e9aa7", fg="#f6cd61", padx=50, font='Helvetica 19 bold')
button_close = Button(root, text="Close!", command=close, bg="#0e9aa7", fg="#f6cd61", padx=50, font='Helvetica 19 bold')

# create the image label but don't yet put image there
# so that it can be done in the `start()` function
# so that it resets every time you press `start()`
image_label = Label(root)

root.mainloop()
```

And here the above code without comments (but take time to read them to get all the suggestions):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


img_names = ['flower1.jpg', 'flower2.jpg', 'flower3.jpg', 'flower4.jpg']
index = 0


def right_pic():
    global index
    index += 1
    if index == len(img_lst):
        index = 0
    image_label.config(image=img_lst[index])


def start():
    global index
    index = 0
    image_label.config(image=img_lst[index])
    image_label.grid(row=0)
    button_right.place(x=900, y=950)
    button_close.place(x=700, y=950)


def close():
    image_label.grid_forget()
    button_close.place_forget()
    button_close.place_forget()


root = Tk()
root.geometry('1920x1080')

img_lst = []
for img in img_names:
    image = Image.open(img).resize((1920, 950), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    img_lst.append(photo)

buttons = Button(root, text="Start!", command=start, bg="#29a8ab", fg="#cccccc", padx=50, font='Helvetica 19 bold')
buttons.place(x=960, y=540)

button_right = Button(root, text="Next!", command=right_pic, bg="#0e9aa7", fg="#f6cd61", padx=50, font='Helvetica 19 bold')
button_close = Button(root, text="Close!", command=close, bg="#0e9aa7", fg="#f6cd61", padx=50, font='Helvetica 19 bold')

image_label = Label(root)

root.mainloop()
```

You can easily see how much shorter this code is, but you also have to understand
how expandable it is since all you really need to add more images is to add more names to the list (or use the `os.listdir()` method mentioned in comments).

Note that I didn't test any of the codes since I didn't have the images but they should work (if they don't, please tell me, I will try to fix that).

Some sources:

- [Great unofficial `tkinter` docs (I use them quite a lot when I have questions about `tkinter`)](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/)
- [Simpler unofficial `tkinter` docs (they are probably easier to understand and include examples)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm)
- [This is a playlist of `tkinter` tutorials but the one this link leads to is actually about image viewer (they are all pretty great but this is on topic)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zg4c92pNFeo&list=PLCC34OHNcOtoC6GglhF3ncJ5rLwQrLGnV&index=9)
- [For other python tutorials I really suggest Corey Schafer (not that much GUIs but the tutorials are very well made)](https://www.youtube.com/user/schafer5)

If you have any more questions, ask them, I will try my best to answer them.